# PHP Set time to Pacific daylight saving time

Tags: php, time, dst

In a PHP site, I have the current time setting:

D j M Y, G:ia

How do I change that to reflect current pacific time with the daylight saving time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://us.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to set the timezone in which all date functions are run. PHP date functions take care of daylight saving time (DST) for you if you just want the current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // or wherever you are

$time = time();

if ($time >= strtotime("Second Sunday March 0")  && $time < strtotime("First Sunday November 0")) 
{

    echo date('m/d/y h:i a', $time);

} else {

    echo date('m/d/y h:i a', $time);

}
```